# separate the dataset as per rank in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dataset which includes name of employees, balance, date and employees has separate rank number.

```
df.show();
+------------+----------+-------+----+
|    Employee|      date|balance|rank|
+------------+----------+-------+----+
|      A     |2016-02-05|   2143|   1|
|      A     |2016-07-05|    231|   2|
|      A     |2016-08-05|    447|   3|
|      A     |2017-10-05|    779|   4|
|      A     |2018-03-05|    255|   5|
|      A     |2018-05-05|    246|   6|
|      A     |2018-08-05|    378|   7|
|      A     |2018-11-05|  10635|   8|
|      A     |2019-06-05|     49|   9|
|      A     |2020-02-05|      0|  10|
|      A     |2020-04-05|    244|  11|
|      A     |2020-05-05|      0|  12|
|      A     |2020-09-05|    424|  13|
|      C     |2016-05-05|   1506|   1|
|      C     |2017-06-05|     52|   2|
|      C     |2017-09-05|    723|   3|
|      C     |2017-11-05|     23|   4|
+------------+----------+-------+----+
```

I have to separate this dataset as per rank. so my expected output is

```
table1
+------------+----------+-------+----+
|    Employee|      date|balance|rank|
+------------+----------+-------+----+
|      A     |2016-02-05|   2143|   1|
|      A     |2016-07-05|    231|   2|
|      A     |2016-08-05|    447|   3|
|      A     |2017-10-05|    779|   4|
|      A     |2018-03-05|    255|   5|
|      A     |2018-05-05|    246|   6|
|      A     |2018-08-05|    378|   7|
|      A     |2018-11-05|  10635|   8|
|      A     |2019-06-05|     49|   9|
|      A     |2020-02-05|      0|  10|
|      A     |2020-04-05|    244|  11|
|      A     |2020-05-05|      0|  12|
|      A     |2020-09-05|    424|  13|
+------------+----------+-------+----+


table2

+------------+----------+-------+----+
|    Employee|      date|balance|rank|
+------------+----------+-------+----+
|      C     |2016-05-05|   1506|   1|
|      C     |2017-06-05|     52|   2|
|      C     |2017-09-05|    723|   3|
|      C     |2017-11-05|     23|   4|
+------------+----------+-------+----+
```

I used window function for getting this rank but I didn't get how can I get separate tables like this. I am using spark 2.0.0 and java.

```
     WindowSpec ws = Window.partitionBy(Employee).orderBy(date);                                  
     data.withColumn( "rank", rank().over(ws) )
```

Comment: So basically you want separate datasets for Each unique employee?
For this, what you can do is to get the distinct employee values first, and then for each employee value get the dataset by doing a filter on the original dataset. You can do the ranking later on each of the separated datasets.

Comment: oky let me try this.

Comment: i got the distinct values  by  `Dataset<Row> df2 = data.select(df).distinct();`
 now I have to filter this into df (Original dataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code to achieve this, by filtering for the distinct values of Employee:

```
//Getting the distinct columns
List<Row> distinctColumns = df.select("Employee").distinct().collectAsList();

//Initializing empty list for the new DataFrames
ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> newDFs = new ArrayList<>();

WindowSpec ws = Window.orderBy("date");

//Filtering by the distinct column values and adding to the list.
for (Row distinctColumn : distinctColumns) {
    String colName = distinctColumn.getString(0);

    newDFs.add(
            df.filter(col("Employee").$eq$eq$eq(colName))
                    .withColumn("rank", rank().over(ws))
    );
}

// show all the new DFs
for (Dataset<Row> aDF : newDFs) {
    aDF.show();
}
```